# Why sometimes we need to initialize structs while sometimes not?

Tags: c#

Let's say we have the following code:

```
struct Point {
   public Int32 m_x, m_y;
}

class Rectangle {
   Point p;
}

//Program.cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
   Point p;
   int i = p.m_x  // does't compile, unassigned field m_x
}
```

so we need to initialize the struct:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   Point p;
   p.m_x = 0; 
   int i = p.m_x;  // compile OK now
}
```

or we can all struct's default parameterless constructor to initialize its fields:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   Point p = new P();
   int i = p.m_x   //OK
}
```

so it looks like we need to initialize structs, but if the struct is a field in a  in a class then it doesn't need to be initialized:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
   int i = r.p.m_x;    //   comile OK
}
```

it still compile, even though I didn't initialize structs. And I checked the IL code and found `Rectangle`'s constructor doesn't call the struct's parameterless constructor neither.

Comment: "*In C#, you must initialize a declared variable before it can be used. Because a structure-type variable can't be null (unless it's a variable of a nullable value type), you must instantiate an instance of the corresponding type*" - Fields that are of a value type, do not need to be initialized, they however will be `default`

Comment: @JohnG sorry I was coping my code, forget to comment out

Comment: The compiler may elide the actual default initializer, as the default value (using `localsinit` rather than an actual constructor) is the same anyway. Furthermore, it's not your (calling code's) business how `Rectangle` initializes, just that it does so, and therefore `new Rectangle()` is guaranteed to have an initialized field. Aside: `Rectangle` is a struct, not a class, not that it matters.

Comment: @Charlieface `Rectangle` is a class in my code

Answer (score 1):

A local variable need to be initialised:

[Instantiation of a structure type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#instantiation-of-a-structure-type)

> **In C#, you must initialize a declared variable before it can be used.**
> Because a structure-type variable can't be null (unless it's a
> variable of a nullable value type), you must instantiate an instance
> of the corresponding type.

In regards to fields, let's look at the [C# ECMA 334 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/)

**15.5.5 Field initialization**

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
> instance field, **is the default value**

**10.3 Default values**

> ...
>
> The default value of a variable depends on the type of the variable
> and is determined as follows:
>
> - For a variable of a value-type, **the default value is the same as the value computed by the value-type’s default constructor**.

**9.3.3 Default constructors**

> All value types implicitly declare a public parameterless instance constructor called the default constructor. The default constructor
> returns a **zero-initialized instance known as the default value for
> the value type**:
>
> - For all simple-types, the default value is the value produced by a bit pattern of all zeros:
>
>   - For sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, and ulong, the default value is 0.
>   - For char, the default value is '\x0000'.
>   - For float, the default value is 0.0f.
>   - For double, the default value is 0.0d.
>   - For decimal, the default value is 0.0m.
>   - For bool, the default value is false.
> - For an enum-type E, the default value is 0, converted to the type E.
>   9 Types
> - For a struct-type, the default value is the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference
>   type fields to null.

Comment: @Charlieface :)

Comment: @Charlieface do you mean Suppress emitting of localsinit flag?

Comment: I was referring to the actual flag. Changed my mind, looks like it doesn't actually rely on it even in Release.